# reading kwargs into __init__

Tags: python, class, init, keyword-argument

In **init** method in a class I want to read keys as self.key from a dict kwarg and assign values to them. Look at code to understand.

```
class Abc:
    def __init__(self,**kwarg):
        for key,value in kwarg.items():
            self.key = value
obj = class(name = 'josh', age = 23, country = 'UK')
print(dir(obj))
```

obj has only key attribute. I get it why it has key. But I don't know how to read keys to self.key? I think you can get the question.
What I except is obj must have name, age, country attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```py
class Abc:
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        for key, value in kwarg.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Laurent